# Undefined variable in blade when passing variable from controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I want to return some string from `model` and `controller`, but it always says undefined variable although it passed successfully when I check it with `dd($a)` and `dd($b)`. What did I do wrong ?

`about.blade:`

```
@extends('layout.template');
@section('homeContainer');

<p> {{ $a }} </p>
<br>
<p>{{ $b }}</p>
@endsection
```

`AboutController :`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\AboutModel;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
    //
    public static function info(){
        $a = AboutModel::info();
        $b = "This data is from controller";
    

        return view('about', compact('a', 'b'));
    }
}
```

`AboutModel :`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AboutModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public static function Info(){
        $a = "This value is from model";
        return $a;
    }
}
```

`Routes :`

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about', [
        "name" => AboutController::info(),
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `static` functions?

Comment: That's not how you setup the Route to use that Controller method. Check the documentation again: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#basic-routing. Should be `Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'info']);`. You code is returning the view, but you're not passing `$a` or `$b` to it. And @JeremyHarris is correct; the Controller method should not be static, but rather `public function info()`; the Model one is mostly irrelevant to your question though.

Comment: @JeremyHarris because when I remove it then it would show an `Non-static method App\Http\Controllers\AboutController::info() cannot be called statically` error

Comment: Where did you see this syntax? Was it in a tutorial or something? Cause this is just completely incorrect for how you use Routes and Controllers in Laravel 

Comment: @TimLewis well in various tutorial, because when I do the basic one and following the docs it always not working

Comment: Your code should work as `public function info(){ ... });` and `Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'info']);`; remove the `static`, and adjust the route; everything else is fine. Does that work, or no?

Comment: @TimLewis it will return this error `Non-static method App\Http\Controllers\AboutController::info() cannot be called statically` 


I found the problem though, I was wrong declarating my model in my controller , I change it to 
`$model = new AboutModel();
 $a = $model->Info();`
and I change the route based on what you said and it works fine

Comment: Oh, that's likely a separate issue. You have `public static function Info(){`, but you're doing `AboutModel::info();`; `Info` vs `info` 

Comment: @TimLewis ah yes also typo lmao, even so, when i fix the typo it also return this error `Non static method 'Info' should not be called statically.` because of bad model declaration to variable

Comment: @RaflyAndrian remove the static from the controller info method, leave the static in the model info method and use the route declaration TimLewis commented above. You should not get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies!, turn out I was wrong declarating the model as variable and the routes,

for the routes I change it to

```
Route::get('/about',[AboutController::class,'info']);
```

and for the controller and model I remove the static and change the model declaration

`Controller :`

```
 public function info()
    {
        $model = new AboutModel();
        $a = $model->Info();
        $b = "This data is from controller";

        return view('about', compact('a', 'b'));
    }
```

`Model :`

```
public function Info(){
        $a = "This value is from model";
        return $a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the controller never run, only the callback in the web.php file runs.
this means you do not have a and b variables but only a name variable

Answer (score 1):

Route declaration is not correct. Route can't handle rendered blade code as return response.  Please check below code for web.php file.

```
<?php
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
 
Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'info'])->name("info");
```

Rest code is fine. It will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In `web.php`, you should write the following code:

```
Route::get('/about',[AboutController::class,'info']);
```